# How a character from the future, reincarnated in the medieval times, could use their knowledge without being accused of witchcraft?

Tags: society, medieval, technological-development, scientific-development, reincarnation

The setting: more or less our regular medieval times, no magic or magical creatures, but religion is big and most people believe in folklore and superstition.

The plot: character from the far future reincarnates as someone in the medieval times(how far in the future they are from hasn't been established yet, but something between nowadays and sometime in the future where stuff like gene modification, human augmentation and space travel(solar system only) are a reality).

The character has an amazing ability to learn and memorize, so everything they learned in their "past life" is inside their head stored like books in a library or files in a computer.The character decides to escape their destiny of a poor commoner's life by using their knowledge from the future in order to both develop themselves(as much as they can with what they have available) and find a way to make a new path for them, a new life.

However, there is always the danger of being accused of witchcraft for whatever reason, and this character has started their journey as a kid of 6~10, so they don't have the means to defend themselves for now.So what they could do in order to achieve their goals(develop self, develop technology and find ways to gain money and independency) while still a kid, and after growing up what they could work with that would make them well known and requested even by nobles and royals?

Comment: Isnt this more of question of  character development or Writing than world building? Also as long as he isnt a bloody D*ck then no one would care? This person is very smart people would rather do stand with him than against him.  People were only accused of which craft when other things were going wrong. Crops failing witches !

Comment: Technically worldbuilding, because the whole story will be about this character dealing with their new situation(basically making modern/future things into the medieval period) and everything that happens around them and with those they interact with due to their "inventions".

Comment: @GrayLabrys you've still described *story*, though. And you're talking about *character's actions*.

Comment: This is mildly off-topic and but also very broad. You could make it more specific, like "how could my character invent the steam engine in the 1300s with all the modern knowledge but no tools, without attracting attention", but that would also be about a character's actions. That said, "how could my immortal avoid attention" is a popular question that's considered on-topic, so I'm unconvinced.

Comment: You might want to take a look at a science fiction classic: *Lest Darkness Fall* by L. Sprague de Camp. His main character, Martin Padway, is a 20th Century archaeologist who somehow ends up in the city of Rome in the sixth century A.D. He occasionally gets accused of witchcraft, but manages to persevere as he "invents" the still, the printing press, and other useful things. De Camp was interested in history and archaeology and tried hard to make his depiction of that setting as realistic as he could.

Answer (score 6):

**Your character is not going to be accused of being a witch at all**

The frequency of witch-hunting is rather exaggerated in discussions about medieval times. The Witch Hunting craze was a feature of the Early Modern Period, not the Middle Ages. During the “Dark Ages” belief in witchcraft was considered heresy, with accusations, promotion, or subscribing to such beliefs being made illegal in the Holy Roman Empire in 785 AD at the [Council of Paderborn] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Paderborn)

The Lombard Code of 643 AD even states “ Let nobody presume to kill a foreign serving maid or female servant as a witch, for it is not possible, nor ought to be believed by Christian minds.” The Saxon King Athelstan decreed: “ And we have ordained respecting witch-crafts, and lybacs [read lyblac "sorcery"], and morthdaeds ["murder, mortal sin"]: if any one should be thereby killed, and he could not deny it, that he be liable in his life. But if he will deny it, and at threefold ordeal shall be guilty; that he be 120 days in prison: and after that let kindred take him out, and give to the king 120 shillings, and pay the wer to his kindred, and enter into borh for him, that he evermore desist from the like.”

Simply put, if you are in Early Medieval Europe in what will become France, Germany, England  or Italy, you will not be killed by the authorities on account of witchcraft.

Now you must be thinking “Wait! What about all the witch burnings and the Bible verses about witchcraft?” There are two reasons why they’re not relevant to the medieval period and why your character will be safe.

The first is that the famous verse “Thou shall not suffer a witch to live” (Exodus 22:18) isn’t as cut and dry as it may seem. What constituted a witch was a major point of discussion within the Church, and some translators think it refers to poisoners or providers of abortions, as outlined in this [article] (https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.haaretz.com/amp/archaeology/thou-shalt-not-suffer-a-witch-to-live-a-murderous-mistranslation-1.5443682) The other reason why this wasn’t as relevant was that witchcraft was also highly tied to pagan worship or idolatry, something that actually **would** get you killed in Christian Europe (depending on where you were).

It was not until centuries after the medieval period had ended that the witch craze began in earnest. Malleus Maleficarum, the infamous textbook for witch hunters was published in 1486, well into the renaissance. Even then the bulk of witch trials did not occur until the 16th and 17th centuries. The vast number of “witches” being burnt at the stake came about due to the massive destabilization caused by the Thirty Years War (1618-1648). People were killed for witches because it seemed like the whole world was coming apart. Famines and massacres devastated the population, and the Catholic Church’s moral authority had been severely harmed by the rise of Protestantism. People were desperate for something to make sense, an enemy they could latch onto and blame. So who were desperate and pious peasants going to blame for the collapse of all they cared about? Why the Devil himself, and his  mortal lackeys, who conveniently tended to be already unpopular, deviant, or widows who either had land or were a burden.

But I digress. If you want to avoid being accused of witchcraft, just avoid being a tempting scapegoat and don’t give any indications of not being Christian.

You can make all the technical advances in the world, as long as you give credit to  Jesus Christ, avoid making enemies, and pay your tithes and feudal rent